# Get value in enum variants

Tags: rust, enums

I am trying to get the inner values of an `enum` with many newtypes, like so (only two to simplify):

```
enum NewType {
    Integer(i32),
    Null,
}

impl From<i32> for NewType {
    fn from(int: i32) -> Self {
        Self::Integer(int)
    }
}

impl NewType {
    fn into_inner<T>(&self) -> Option<T>
        where
            T: Into<NewType>,
        {
        match self {
            NewType::Integer(v) => Some(*v),
            NewType::Null => None,
        }
    }
}
```

But I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:32:41
   |
27 |     fn into_inner<T>(&self) -> Option<T>
   |                   - this type parameter
...
32 |             NewType::Integer(v) => Some(*v),
   |                                         ^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `i32`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `i32`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `testrs` due to previous error
```

And when trying:

```
impl<T> From<NewType> for T {
    fn from(new_value: NewType) -> Option<T> 
    where
        T: Into<NewType>,
    {
        match new_value {
            NewType::Integer(v) => Some(v),
            NewType::Null => None,
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`NewType`)
  --> src/main.rs:14:6
   |
14 | impl<T> From<NewType> for T {
   |      ^ type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`NewType`)
   |
   = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
   = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0210`.
error: could not compile `testrs` due to previous error
```

What would be the best way to get these inner values in Rust?

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `impl TryInto<_, Error=()> for NewType` for each possible type?

Comment: You're trying to make a function which would "unwrap" the variant which corresponds to the type parameter, right?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that rust has no idea how to produce `T` since you don't tell it how to act. The current implementation always returns a `Option<i32>` which does not line up with the function signature. You have the `Into<NewType>` trait bound, but you never make use of this trait.
It seems like you actually want to reverse the trait bound so `i32` is turned `into` `T`.

```rust
impl NewType {
    fn into_inner<T>(&self) -> Option<T>
        where i32: Into<T>,
    {
        match self {
            NewType::Integer(v) => Some((*v).into()),
            NewType::Null => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chayim I have updated the question with the full `cargo check` errors.

Comment: @Cerberus I am trying to create a method that would allow me to get the inner value of any `NewType` tuple variant. E.g., `NewType::Integer(5)` would return `5`, `NewType::Bool(true)` would return `true`, and `NewType::Array(vec![1, 2, 3])` would return `vec![1, 2, 3]`.